# GA4: Inconsistent Conversion Data when Secondary Dimensions are added

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

My Conversion data in GA4 fluctuates wildly when I add secondary dimensions.

If I go to the Traffic Acquisition report and add "Session source" as a secondary dimension, I see 21 conversions credited to LinkedIn:

[image]

But if I add "Landing page" as a secondary dimension, my conversions goes down to 10:

[image]

If I add "City" as a secondary dimension, my conversions goes down to 2:

[image]

And if I check my conversions by going to "Conversions" and adding "Session source" as a secondary dimension, my conversions from LinkedIn goes down to 0:

[image]

Anyone experienced this before and have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Bump, I'm experiencing this as well.

Comment: I actually ended up fixing this. Go to Admin > Data Settings > Data Collection and turn off "Google signals data collection".